# How can i create a shallow route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this routes in rails, other developer i made that

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :articles do
        resources :posts
      end
    end
  end
```

now i want to test it by postman, but i dont understand how will be the url of the endpoint

i tested this url

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles?id=1&posts=1

but just i am getting this error

```
"#<ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::ArticlesController\n\n
```

Comment: run `rails routes | grep article` to check the routes generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type `rails routes` to print all routes you have defined so far.
Then you'll know what the routes URL should be looked like

In your example, it should be like `GET api/v1/articles/1/posts/1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can open `localhost:3000/routes` to view and search your route helper paths and urls

Answer (score 0):

When you [nest a route in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) the "parent" resource is added to the path as a *static segment* and a *dynamic segment* consisting of the parent id:

```
/api/v1/articles/:article_id/posts/:id
```

You can display the routes in your app with the `rails routes` command or visiting `http://localhost:3000/routes` in newer versions of Rails.

This is basically a regular expression on steroids which the incoming request URI is matched against.

Query string parameters are not used for matching routes in which is why `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles?id=1&posts=1` is being routed to  `ArticlesController#index` since it matches `/api/v1/articles`.

In general in [Rails flavor REST](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) query string parameters are merely used for additional information such as paging or filtering. Not for routing to resources.

If you wanted to declare this [as a shallow route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) you pass the `shallow` option to the `resources` macro:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :articles do
      resources :posts, shallow: true
    end
  end
end
```

This will generate the member route `/api/v1/posts/:id` for a single post while the collection routes (new, index, create) are still nested.

```
max@maxbook ~/p/sandbox_7 (main)> rails routes | grep posts
                    api_v1_article_posts GET    /api/v1/articles/:article_id/posts(.:format)                                                      api/v1/posts#index
                                         POST   /api/v1/articles/:article_id/posts(.:format)                                                      api/v1/posts#create
                 new_api_v1_article_post GET    /api/v1/articles/:article_id/posts/new(.:format)                                                  api/v1/posts#new
                        edit_api_v1_post GET    /api/v1/posts/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/posts#edit
                             api_v1_post GET    /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                                                                       api/v1/posts#show
                                         PATCH  /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                                                                       api/v1/posts#update
                                         PUT    /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                                                                       api/v1/posts#update
                                         DELETE /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                                                                       api/v1/posts#destroy
```

This option is also "inherited" so you can pass it to the parent resource to make all the nested routes shallow:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :articles, shallow: true do
      resources :posts
      resources :photos
      resources :videos
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The error suggests that you have not yet created a controller that corresponds to the route.

Folder structure:
`app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb`

```rb
class Api::V1::PostsController
end
```

Comment: You need to read the question again. The error is "uninitialized constant Api::V1::ArticlesController" which is because the request path is wrong.